# Graphs with the same Laplacian eigenvalues

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, isospectrality

Let $L$ be the 
[Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix)
for a simple graph $G$ of $n$ vertices,
and $\lambda_0,\ldots,\lambda_{n-1}$ its $n$ eigenvalues.

> ***Q***. 
>   What is the cardinality of the class of $n$-vertex graphs $\cal G$,
>   that each have the same Laplacian eigenvalues as $G$?
>   Presumably $G$ is not uniquely determined by its eigenvalues.
>   What are examples of pairs or clusters of graphs with the same eigenvalues?

The smallest and second-smallest eigenvalues are the 
spectral gap and algebraic connectivity of $G$ respectively,
and the third-smallest relates to partitioning $G$ into pieces.
See the 2015 MO question,
[Spectral theory of graph Laplacian besides $\lambda_2$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136805/6094),
for further properties of the eigenvalues.

I also wonder if the new result that eigenvectors are
determined by eigenvalues might play a role here.

---

- Natalie Wolchover.
  "Neutrinos Lead to Unexpected Discovery in Basic Math."
  [Quanta](https://www.quantamagazine.org/neutrinos-lead-to-unexpected-discovery-in-basic-math-20191113/). 2019.
- Peter B. Denton, Stephen J. Parke, Terence Tao, Xining Zhang.
  "Eigenvectors from Eigenvalues."
  [arXiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795).
  2019.
- Van Mieghem, Piet. "Graph eigenvectors, fundamental weights and centrality metrics for nodes in networks." [arXiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4580). 2014.

Comment: W.r.t. your last line: it seems that the formula for computing eigenvectors from eigenvalues has been discovered before in the context of eigenvalues of graphs, see here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4580. I found this link through the addendum to the quanta-article you link to, so perhaps you already knew this.

Comment: @Vincent: Thanks, added Van Mieghem's preprint to the list.

Comment: trackback: http://www.findstat.org/St001496, in particular, for at most 5 vertices, there are no coincidences, for 6 vertices there are two pairs, and for 7 vertices there are also a few triplets with the same list of eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinRubey, for the calculation. Impressively concise code!

Comment: Would it be interesting to consider graphs with the same *set* of eigenvalues, too?  (There are much more coincidences in this case.)

Comment: @MartinRubey: I was particularly focussed on the ordering, because the position of the eigenvalues ("second-smallest," etc.) corresponds to specific spectral properties of the graph.

Comment: @MartinRubey: How can I get, e.g., the two graphs on $6$ vertices with the same eigenvalues? I don't know how to interpret `([(0,5),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,5)],6) => 2` in the output, which seems to be just one of the two graphs. Thanks.

Comment: This line just means that the graph on 6 vertices with edges (0,5),(1,3),... has statistic value 2, so, there are in total 2 graphs having the spectrum of this graph.  You get a picture by hovering with the mouse over the line (and waiting a little).  There is currently no way to filter by statistic value, although that is a planned feature.